# secure a API request form?

Tags: php

Ok I have the following php:

```
    <?php

 //function to return nice url's for our pdf's 
 function seoUrl($string) {
    //Lower case everything
    $string = strtolower($string);
    //Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    //Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
//Set up our POST variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$zipcode = str_replace(' ', '',$_POST['zipcode']);
//Store your XML Request in a variable
    $input_xml = urlencode('<ExternalReturnLabelRequest> 
                            <CustomerName>'.$name .'</CustomerName> 
                            <CustomerAddress1>'.$address1.'</CustomerAddress1> 
                            <CustomerAddress2>'.$address2.'</CustomerAddress2> 
                            <CustomerCity>Washington</CustomerCity>
                            <CustomerState>DC</CustomerState> 
                            <CustomerZipCode>'.$zipcode.'</CustomerZipCode> 
                            <LabelFormat>NOI</LabelFormat>
                            <LabelDefinition>Zebra-4X6</LabelDefinition> 
                            <ServiceTypeCode>020</ServiceTypeCode> 
                            <AddressOverrideNotification>false</AddressOverrideNotification> 
                            <CallCenterOrSelfService>Customer</CallCenterOrSelfService> 
                            <AddressValidation>false</AddressValidation>
                            </ExternalReturnLabelRequest>');

//start Curl tried file_get_contents but to no avail..
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,"https://returns.usps.com/Services/ExternalCreateReturnLabel.svc/ExternalCreateReturnLabel?externalReturnLabelRequest=".$input_xml);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

//decode the response this will fail if nothing returned 
$pdfdecode = base64_decode($query);

if($pdfdecode != false){

    $urlfriendlyname = seoUrl($name);
    $myFile = "labels/labelfor".$urlfriendlyname.$zipcode.".pdf";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $pdfdecode);
    fclose($fh);


    header("Location: http://thedarkroom.com/wp-content/themes/thedarkroom2012/".$myFile); 
    exit();

    /*
    MID 201198
    */
}else{
    header("Location: http://thedarkroom.com/label/?labelerror=".$query); 
    exit();
}
echo "<pre>";

var_dump($pdfdecode);
var_dump($query);

echo "</pre>";
```

and this html:

```
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/get_labels.php" >
                <fieldset id="labelfields">
                    <label for="name">Name</label><br>
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"/> <br>
                    <label for="address1">Address Line one</label>
                    <input name="address1" type="text" placeholder="Address line one"/><br>
                    <label for="address2">Address Line two</label>
                    <input name="address2" type="text" placeholder="Address line two"/><br>
                    <label for="zipcode">Zip code</label>
                    <input name="zipcode" type="text"  placeholder="Zip Code"/><br>
                    <label for="CustomerState">State</label>
                    <input name="CustomerState" type="text"  placeholder="State"/><br>
                    <label for="CustomerCity">City</label>
                    <input name="CustomerCity" type="text"  placeholder="City"/><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create Label" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

what are the best practises for securing this?
I've gone for strip tags...

Comment: Define "securing". What do you want to prevent?

Comment: really not sure, since I'm not entirly sure what possible hack this may have... I was assuming that there where best practises regarding forms...

Comment: That's far too broad a question for Stackoverflow. Start your research at https://www.owasp.org

Comment: how is that so, I'm not asking a open ended question i'm asking how to secure a form.

Comment: "Securing forms" is a very big topic. There are lots of different attacks that can be made against them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data that comes to your server must be checked and sanitized. Always. No exception.

Escape potentially dangerous characters. The specific characters you should be cautious with vary depending on the context in which the data is used and the server platform you employ, but all server-side languages have functions for this.

Limit the incoming amount of data to allow only what's necessary.

Sandbox uploaded files (store them on a different server and allow access to the file only through a different subdomain or even better through a fully different domain name).

For preventing cross-site forgeries please refer this article 
http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Comment: perfect just what i was looking for!